Accepting Android SDK licenses
When I try to accept the license from vs for api 35, in the console I get
"Aceptando licencias de Android SDK...
Version information not found for component Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image r3 [System Image: X86 API 27 (Google Inc.)]
Version information not found for component Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image r7 [System Image: X86_64 API 33 (Google Inc.)]
[RunLongOperation] exception
System.Exception: Error al intentar aceptar licencias de Android"
If I run the command sdkmanager --licenses from the path to the sdk that I have configured in vs, it installs it but vs does not recognize it and keeps asking for the license

Did you update the .net version to the .net 9?

Yes i did it. thanks, i solved

I solved it by changing the Java version from 8 to 22
